# How do I setup my Mac to test Postfix receiving emails

Tags: email, postfix-mta

A Rails app I'm working on will receive emails with attachments and then process those attachments.

What I would like to do is configure Postfix so that I can send an email with attachments from Mail.app to an email address that will be picked up by Postfix locally. I'm quite happy with getting the mail contents into my app once it's been received in Postfix.

I've tried setting `robin-fishers-macbook.local` to `localhost` in my hosts file in the hope that email sent to robinjfisher@robin-fishers-macbook.local might be routed locally but no joy.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Robin

Comment: You may need an MX DNS record, that's not something you can do with a hosts file.

Comment: I'm concerned that's the route I'll end up having to go down e.g. setting up a public server with an MX record and testing to that. My problem is that it slows down testing when having to email large files into the wild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm concerned that's the route I'll end up having to go down e.g. setting up a public server with an MX record and testing to that.

You won't need to use a public server. If you setup a DNS server locally, perhaps using [a guide like this one for Mac OSX](http://neva.li/post/122596681/using-a-local-nameserver-on-mac-os-x), you can create a zone for `robin-fishers-macbook.local`, point everything to 127.0.0.1 (or if your actually running this on another Mac, point it to the IP that has postfix running on it), and add an `IN MX 10 127.0.0.1`. Then you just need to make sure to change your resolver to use the local DNS instead of the one you normally use. Things like google and other domains will still resolve as well as the `robin-fishers-macbook.local` domain.

Comment: Thanks for this. From reading up on this, particularly [this forum post](http://macosx.com/forums/unix-x11/21094-dns-server-working-mx-records.html), it appears that email sent from Mail.app will resolve using the email provider's DNS records. What I'll do is use polling of a remote inbox for test purposes to get the emails into the app but your answer is definitely right - I just haven't the inclination to set it up!